# Javascript stored procedure: empty argument passed

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am attempting to create a stored procedure which takes an array as input argument and runs a select statement for each element of the array

```sql
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE sproc(PRODUCT array)
RETURNS varchar 
LANGUAGE javascript 
AS
$$
var query = `SELECT COUNT(*) AS PRODUCT_COUNT FROM FIVETRAN.DBT_EXTERNAL_REPORTING.REVENUE WHERE SITE_ID='ksisk5kZRvk' AND PRODUCT_NAME=:1 ORDER BY 1`;
var i;
var out = "";
var product_count;
for(i = 0; i < PRODUCT.length; i++){       
out += PRODUCT[i] ;
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqltext: query, binds: [out]});
var result = stmt.execute();
product_count = stmt.getColumnValue(1)
return product_count;
result.next();
   }
return "Done";
$$;
```

When I run it like so

```sql
CALL sproc(array_construct('product-annual','product-monthly'));
```

I get the error

```
SQL Error [100183] [P0000]: Execution error in store procedure SPROC:
empty argument passed
At Snowflake.createStatement, line 8 position 29
```

I want to pass to my query each element of the array ie product[0] then product[1] but I am obviously missing something here.

I am attempting to create a stored procedure that takes an array as an input argument and runs a select statement for each element of the array. The binding variable is empty which is why I am getting this error. Why can't I pass PRODUCT[i] as bind variable?

(question from https://www.reddit.com/r/snowflake/comments/1aljgg9/javascript_stored_procedure_empty_argument_passed/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is `sqltext`: It should be `sqlText`.

Then you need to call `result.next()` before calling out `stmt.getColumnValue(1)`.

But instead of `stmt.getColumnValue(1)` you need to call `result.getColumnValue(1)`.